# Can I have a FileUpload control inside the Complete step of a Wizard that is surrounded by an UpdatePanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Wizard control surrounded with an UpdatePanel and I want a FileUpload control within the complete step.  I am aware that a FileUpload control will only work inside an UpdatePanel if a trigger is added to the UpdatePanel, but, my UpdatePanel cannot find the Button1 control in the example below.  I believe this is simply a "feature" of the Complete step.  Is there another way (preferably a simple one) to do this inside of the Complete step?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server">
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Step 1">
                </asp:WizardStep>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Step 2" StepType="Complete">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                </asp:WizardStep>
            </WizardSteps>
        </asp:Wizard>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after browsing the internet for hours I have found the solution.  What is needed is another nested UpdatePanel within the Wizard Complete step with a PostBackTrigger on Button1 and a matching PostBackTrigger on the outer UpdatePanel.

Like the following:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Wizard ID="Wizard1" runat="server">
            <WizardSteps>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Step 1">
                </asp:WizardStep>
                <asp:WizardStep ID="WizardStep2" runat="server" Title="Step 2" StepType="Complete">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                        <ContentTemplate/>
                    <UpdatePanel/>
                </asp:WizardStep>
            </WizardSteps>
        </asp:Wizard>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Also, you may find that the first time you upload a file your control does not have the file.  I don't know the reason but you may need an enctype="multipart/form-data" on your form tag.

I hope someone finds this helpful in the future.

Comment: I take that back...it appears the outer trigger is not needed.  Just the trigger inside the inner UpdatePanel.